# how to find the actual state for the diodes?

Tags: diodes, circuit-analysis

How I can find the actual state of the two diodes for example " ON , ON " ?
What are the steps ?

[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: Are you sure this is the right schematic? There is a short-circuit from 5V->D2->D1...

Comment: There's alas [no easy/algorithmic answer (in general)](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/192016/54580). Every combination of on/off could, in theory, lead to a solution for a random circuit. You need to use a bit of intuition to eliminate those that don't look likely to work.

Comment: Golaž yes the prof gave it as a home work

Comment: And since this a homework with no attempt at solution... the typical comment is "What have you tried?"

Comment: based on what I can eliminate a circuit ? Respawned Fluff

Comment: i have tried all the assumptions

Comment: ANd which of the assumptions worked, and why did you discount the others?

Comment: I think the state of the diodes is 'burnt out'.

Comment: off off  / on off they don't work cause d2 will be on  , in on on the current in the 10k resistance 0.1 mA up , and the current in 1k resistance is 5 mA down ,  in off on d1 should on so i guess it's on on

Comment: Very closely related question: [Which assumption to consider first when there is more than one diode](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/186667/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to approach this. We "see" that D2's anode is at some positive potential, and that that's the largest positive potential that we can identify by quick inspection (the other are ground and -1V). So assume D2 is forward biased.

To continue we need to assume some diode model and you have told us nothing about that. Let's assume the diode forward drop is zero, i.e. this the simplest qualitative analysis imaginable. Then you have 5V at cathode of D2. And so D1 would be forward biased as well since its anode is also at higher potential than its cathode. So this combination (both forward biased) yields a solution... of sorts. The current that would flow through D1 and D2 would be infinite in this simple model. In real life, diodes have an equivalent series resistance etc., which means they'll blow up but the current won't be infinite. So a quantitative answer depends on assumptions not included in your problem description.